# Adding an existing media image from a programmatically created node

Tags: nodes, forms

I have a form that allows users to upload multiple pictures. These images are saved as media in `admin/content/files`. This upload process is managed by `#managed_file` type. Below is an example

```
$form['upload']['uploaded_file'] = [
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Upload your file'),
    '#multiple' => true,
    '#upload_location' => 'public://my_files/',        
    '#upload_validators' => [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['png gif jpg jpeg'],
        'file_validate_size' => [7500000],
    ],
];
```

After the files are uploaded, AJAX alters the form and it displays the images uploaded with a *Title* and *Description* field. Once all fields are filled out the user submit the changes. In the `submitForm` method, all information is saved as a `image` content type.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $values = $form_state->getValue(['upload','images']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {

        $node = Node::create([
            'type'        => 'image',
            'title'       => $values[$i]['image']['title'],
            'field_image' => [
                'target_id' => $values[$i]['image']['fid'],
                'alt' => $values[$i]['image']['description'],
                'title' => $values[$i]['image']['title'],
            ],
        ]);

        $node->save();
    }
}
```

The node is created and the title is passed, but the image is not. Is the `target_id` not the `fid` of the image?